# Creating client video review pages in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, video, client

We are looking for an easy way to share our work in progress videos with our clients - for feedback.

We are using WordPress.

We want to avoid email/ftp/youtube/vimeo etc... And simply have our clients access a link to our site that we give them.

Is there a way that I can get the following:

- create a directory "client_0001" on our webserver
- upload our client's videos to the directory
- send the link to the server "http://mysite.com/client_0001" to our client
- when the clients accesses the link they will be presented with our wordpress site, but not some post/page but rather a template of the site with html5video/mp4 players in the page for each video that we uploaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real reason to do this using Wordpress. In fact, it would certainly be more work doing it in Wordpress. A decent way to do this would perhaps create a php page with your template/html5 player, and having this page parse a GET variable to display the video. That way you can send your clients links like http://mysite.com/video_preview.php?videofile=somevideofile.mp4

For example:

Directory Structure:

```
example.com/
    previews/
        video_preview.php
        someVideo.mp4
```

Then in video_preview.php, you can parse a GET variable and display any page you want.  Here's a rough example.

```
<?php $video = $_GET['videofile'] ?>
<html>
// The HTML you want to use for the template.  All CSS/JS, etc, etc...make it look pretty. (or dow't)
// Then you'd call your video player, however you want to do that.  Basically, you just dynamically choose the video file based on the URL your client clicks.
<player src=<?php echo $video ?>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I wish I had WordPress** ten years ago when I was hand crafting all those client pages in Dreamweaver...

The only caveat right now is the file size that can be uploaded directly in WP. But this can be solved uploading via FTP to a custom folder and doing a video player [**Shortcode**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to render player+posterframe:

`[vplay file="http://example.com/custom/video.mp4" poster="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/picture.jpg"]`

A custom [**page template**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates), for example, with customized header and footer, that after page creation would have a URL like: `http://example.com/clients/project-name/`.

Password protected for the client's convenience, or some membership in the site for restricted content. Comments form enabled for internal communication. Image gallery if necessary. Among other goodies.

What's good about YouTube and Vimeo are the privacy options and doing the web-format rendering for you. In this WordPress Answers, [Video tutorials in dashboard](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54043/12615), I write about the options.

Comment: As a matter of fact, many times I upload the video and let YouTube do the rendering for me, and download back all web versions using jDownloader. As this method don't eat cpu as doing a render in an old laptop does.